# The change of the tense in the main and the subordinate clauses

Tags: tense, clauses, subordinate-clauses

I have found the two sentences in Michael  Swan's Practical English Usage .(page no 556)

**1.This discovery means that  we will have to spend less on food.**

**2 This Discovery will mean that we spend less on food.**

It was explained that " if the main verb of a sentence  makes it clear that what kind of time the speaker is talking about , it is not necessary for the same time to be indicated again in subordinate clauses"

The author talks about the tenses in the clauses  but I could  not understand whether the change of the tenses in the 
main and subordinate clauses changes the meaning  of the two sentences given above

I would like to know if  both the sentences mean the same thing or do they differ in meaning

Comment: The first sentence is a statement of necessity, the second a statement of reality. The use of *have to* isn't really a matter of tense (because *had to* would indicate the same necessity).

Comment: Jason Bassford. if we say "we will spend less on food",will the meaning be the same, sir?

Comment: It would be the same as the *second* sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question asks about differences in meaning due to changes in the tense, but the example sentences do not only differ in tense.  As pointed out by @Jason Bassford in the comments the inclusion of *have to* introduces a significant change in meaning.  To remove this difference so that your question is solely about tense we can compare the two sentences:

> **1. This discovery means that we will spend less on food**
>
> **2. This discovery will mean that we spend less on food**

The effect of these two sentences is the same, in sentence 1 the current meaning (implication) of the discovery is that in the future we will be spending less on food.  In sentence 2 the future meaning (implication) of the discovery will be that (at that time in the future) we will be spending less on food.

So although there is a difference in expression the *effective meaning* of both sentences is the same - in the future spending on food will be reduced because of this discovery.

Comment: Lambdon, I did not ask ask about the  tense but about the meaning change  because of the change in the tense

Comment: @Jagatha - I am sorry if I was not clear. I have edited the answer to clarrify. I understood your question, and due to the differences  other than tense removed those to be able to explain that there is no difference in meaning resulting from the tense.